# diff output of two python programs in windows cmd

Tags: python, diff

So I am trying to compare output of two python programs, which have files that I will call `trace1.py` and `trace2.py`. Currently I am using process substitution with diff to try and compare their outputs, however I'm having trouble with finding both files, since they are in separate sub-directories of my current directory:

```
diff <(python /subdir1/tracing1.py) <(python /subdir2/tracing2.py)
```

When I run this, I get

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I  think I'm messing up some sort of path formatting, or else I'm using the process substitution incorrectly.

EDIT: In the end I decided that I didn't need to use process substitution, and instead could just diff program output after each program is run. However thanks to `Fallenreaper` in the comments, I was able to find a single command that does what I initially wanted:

```
python subdir1/tracing1.py > outfile1.txt & python subdir2/tracing2.py > outfile2.txt & diff outfile1.txt outfile2.txt
```

Comment: Can you paste the exact command that you are running? What is your directory struc like?

Comment: Maybe something like: `python /path/tracing1.py &1> outfile1.txt & python /path/tracing2.py &1 >outfile2.txt & diff outfile1.txt outfile2.txt`

Comment: If `subdir1` and `subdir2` are subdirectories of the current directory (and not root-level directories), you probably mean `subdir1/tracing1.py` (without the leading slash).

Comment: @Fallenreaper Process substitution captures both output to stdout and stderr, see for example `diff <(echo blah >&2) <(echo blahx)`, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Honestly come to think of it, I don't even need to run both programs one after another. So really I can just redirect output to two separate files and then diff after. I guess I was over complicating things in the end. I guess my curiosity with the error made me want to ask.

Comment: But I will say removing the leading slash did not change anything.

Comment: If the python commands work by themselves, they should work in process substitution.

Comment: The whole point of process substitution is so you can avoid creating all those temporary files.

Comment: Are you doing this on Windows? I've never seen that error message on Linux, and my googling indicates that it's a Windows error message.

Comment: @Barmar Yep, I am a complete idiot. Don't know why I tagged this as bash and why I thought I was working on Unix. I guess work this week has really taken it's toll...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, not enough rep to comment yet :( 
Your line works perfectly when you remove that slash. I would suggest using absolute path names or a relative path from current directory cos that front slash would take you to your root directory.

Cheers.